# what to do if I change the permissions of my home directories to 777, and my google cloud server no longer gives me access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, server, permissions, updates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWyLg.png)

After changing the permissions, I don't get past this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you changed the permission of the directory **.ssh**. This breaks SSH security. You should be able to create a startup script to change the directory `/home/<username>/.ssh` to 700.

- Go to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
- Go to Compute Engine -> VM instances
- Stop the VM instance
- Click the Edit button
- Scroll down to the section **Custom metadata**
- For the key enter **startup-script**
- Enter the following for the value replacing `<username>` with your username:

  `#! /bin/bash`

  `chmod 700 /home/<username>/.ssh`
- Restart the instance

Another method is to use the VM serial console:

[Troubleshooting using the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console)

Comment: I've tried and it still won't allow me access in any way, for some reason it keeps blocking me

Comment: @dany - Use the second method and debug why.

Comment: I have done the complete process, add the following
#!/bin/bash
adduser USERNAME
echo USERNAME:PASSWORD | chpasswd
usermod -aG google-sudoers USERNAME
with my respective username and password, in the Custom Metadata section
and all the other steps, it allows me to do everything well and I can see correctly in the console how the server is restored, however I get the following error


instance-1 login:my_user
Password: 
Login incorrect

even after verifying my username and password and retrying several times, I can't access it at all

Comment: @dany - Password login is disabled by default on Google Cloud VMs. You must edit the OpenSSH configuration file to enable passwords. I wrote an article on how to repair boot disks by mounting them on another VM. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Comment: Thank you very much, it was the best answer I could find, it solved my problem by 80%, I could not conclude it because when mounting the SSD in my new VM it only allows to mount the EFI partition, as for everything else, I was able to correct the problem largely